# jQuery isn't working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I've created a function in `js/custom.js`.
Basically, it aligns posts for me in wordpress by adding a class of `articleAlign`, which will insert content to create a greater gap between the title of the article and the excerpt beneath, this is only necessary when the title of the article does not exceed one line, because for titles that take up two lines, it will push the excerpt of the article down. I want a bigger gap between article titles of one line and the excerpt below them, so that the top of the excerpts are all aligned.

CSS

```
.articleAlign::after {
  display:block;
  height:55px;
  content:"";
}
```

jQuery

```
(function($) {
  function articleAlign() {
    titleLength = $('.entry-title').children('a').text().length;
    if(titleLength < 44) {
    $('.entry-title').addClass('articleAlign');
    }
  }
  articleAlign();
})(jQuery);
```

And of course, here is my [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
```

Note that I'm passing `true` for `$in_footer` so the script is just before the `</body>` tag. (All on one line in original, in the Wordpress `functions.php` right beneath the enqueue for `js/functions.js`.)

Why isn't my class getting added?

Comment: Use the debugger built into your browser to set a breakpoint on your call to `articleAlign`, then step through and examine what's going on in the code as it rights -- does it find the element, does it get the text you expect, what's the length of that text, etc. There's no substitute for debugging.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you so much!

Comment: Side note: Your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. You need to declare `titleLength`.

Comment: jQuery's `text` is an odd duck: Unlike all of jQuery's other getters, which only return the relevant value for the *first* entry in the set, it returns a concatenated string of the text for *all* the entries in the set. So one possible issue is that there is more than one `.entry-title` and you're getting more text than you expect. I picked a Wordpress site at random and found it had *two* `.entry-title` elements, each with the title, rather than one. So perhaps that's it. (But that site's `.entry-title` elements didn't have any `a` in them, so clearly a different design...)

Comment: So before my function articleAlign, I just have to declare titleLength; just like that?

Comment: In this case, you can literally just put `var` in front of `titleLength`. (But this isn't why the code's not working, it's just that you're accidentally creating a global, which is probably not what you want to do.)

Comment: Yes! There are many .entry-titles What should I do to fix that? I've tested my function in a JSFiddle, it works, but I did only have one element of each.

Comment: The requested path for the custom.js file isn't going to the js folder first. It's trying to find custom.js file in the first directory of the theme. But evidently, I have it set to go into the js folder first.

Comment: Should I loop my function for every article?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder maybe something like this?                                         entryTitles = $('.entry-title');
foreach(entryTitles as Title) {
 var titleLength = Title.children('a').text().length;
  if(titleLength < 30) {
   Title.addClass('articleAlign');
  }
}

Comment: Oops sorry, been using php lately. This should work fine:                                               $('.entry-title').each(function(){
 var titleLength = $(this).children('a').text().length;
  if(titleLength < 44) {
    $(this).addClass('articleAlign');
  }
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `text` is an odd duck: Unlike all of jQuery's other getters, which only return the relevant value for the *first* entry in the set, it returns a concatenated string of *all* the entries in the set. So one possible issue is that there is more than one `.entry-title` and you're getting more text than you expect.

Looking at a random Wordpress site, I see that there are *two* `.entry-title` elements, not just one, and each of them contains the title. So `$(".entry-title").children("a").text()` in that case would return a string containing **two** copies of the title.

If that's what's happening in your case, you can use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to just get the first. Also note that `$(".entry-title").children("a")` is ore simply written `$(".entry-title > a")`. So:

```
if ($(".entry-title > a").eq(0).text().length < 44) {
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Should I loop my function for every article?

**If** you want this applied to each of them, yes:

```
(function($) {
    $(".entry-title").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.children("a").first().text().length < 44) {
            $this.addClass("articleAlign");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're awesome dude! Learned a couple new things from you, thanks so much. By the way, I had another function with the same name in a different file that I forgot to take out. But I'm glad you've assisted me. I used the function I made, but I'm going to include the "> a" syntax. Thank you!